# Changing shape of numpy array read from a text file

Tags: python, arrays, text, numpy

I am working in python and am loading a text file that looks like this:

```
3    4

5    6

7    8

9    10
```

I use np.loadtxt('filename.txt') and it outputs an array like this:

```
([[3, 4]
  [5, 6]
  [7, 8]
  [9, 10]])
```

However, I want an array that looks like:

```
([3, 5, 7, 9], [4, 6, 8, 10])
```

Anyone know what I can do besides copying the array and reformatting it manually? I have tried a few things but they don't work.

Comment: I think you're looking for numpy.transpose()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment:

```
>>> x
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
>>> numpy.transpose(x)
array([[ 3,  5,  7,  9],
       [ 4,  6,  8, 10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unpack` option of `np.loadtxt`:

```
np.loadtxt('filename.txt', unpack=True)
```

This will directly give you your array transposed. (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Another option is to use the `transpose` function for your numpy array:

```
your_array = np.loadtxt('filename.txt')
print(your_array)
([[3, 4]
 [5, 6]
 [7, 8]
 [9, 10]])

new_array = your_array.T
print(new_array)
([3, 5, 7, 9], [4, 6, 8, 10])
```

The `transpose` method will return you the transposed array, not transpose in place.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the `transpose` method as follows:

```
import numpy as np

load_textdata = np.loadtxt('filename.txt')
data = np.transpose(load_textdata)
```